# Is there any module in Python using which I can get same data size on disk as in memory?

Tags: python, pickle

I tried pickle but the size on disk is very large. I tried all the protocols; the output file size on disk is more than the size in memory. 
I am using the following code:

```
#Here, a is a string.
def picklate(a):
    picklist.append(a)
    pickle.dump(a,picklefile,2)
```

Comment: What are you pickling? Please provide more code. I don't think it's possible if you're using some serialization protocol and not just dumping data in a binary file. Might be wrong though.

Comment: Its a string. I had mentioned in the question.

Comment: How did you determine the sizes?

Comment: Define 'very large'. What *kind* of string are you pickling? How did you compare sizes?

Comment: The size of the pickle seems to be slightly *smaller* than what `sys.getsizeof` gives as the in-memory size for a pickle of one string.

Comment: @JanneKarila yeah, I noticed that!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Having just written this answer without really paying attention to what pickle actually saves, it's apparent that for strings, pickle is actually pretty much identical to `numpy` in terms of file size. That said, `numpy.save` is good in the general case for storing binary arrays of data, so I'll leave this answer here.

`numpy.save` does a pretty good job of keeping the sizes about the same.

```
import string, random, numpy
mystring = ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for i in range(1000000))
numpy.save('my_file', mystring)
```

You can get it back easily enough:

```
mystring = str(numpy.load('my_file.npy'))
```

You can also use `numpy.savez_compressed` if you want the file even smaller (though the usage of that is slightly different - like `numpy.savez`, it's designed for storing more than one array).